# How to use elasticsearch in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I am totally new in elastic search.
i installed the elastic search in my system.
at localhost:9200 it is showing

```
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Unseen",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.90.10",
    "build_hash" : "0a5781f44876e8d1c30b6360628d59cb2a7a2bbb",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-01-10T10:18:37Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.6"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I included these two gems in my gem file.

```
gem 'tire'
gem 'elasticsearch'
```

I have a movie model & a controller called search_controller.

movie.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
include Tire::Model::Search
include Tire::Model::Callbacks
mapping do
    indexes :title
end
def self.search(params)
        binding.pry
        tire.search(load: true, page: 1, per_page: 10) do
        query { string params[:query]} if params[:query].present?
     end
```

migration for the movies model

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :movies do |t|
        t.string :title
      t.timestamps
    end
    def self.down
        drop_table movies
    end
  end
end
```

search_controller

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if(params[:query]).present?
    @results=Movie.search(params)
    else
    @results=[]
    end
  end
end

view/search/index
<h1>Search#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/search/index.html.erb</p>

<%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<% if @results %>
<% @results.each do |fetchresults| %>
<%= fetchresults.title %> 
<%= fetchresults.year %><br/>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb
resource :search
   root 'search#index'

i know i should index my records to use it in elastic search,but not getting any clue how & where to save those files,& how to use them.
when i am trying to search it is showing an error

```
404 : {"error":"IndexMissingException[[movies] missing]","status":404}
```

Comment: in movie model, use Movie.import and in SearchController use Moview.search params[:query]

Answer (score 6):

When I added elasticsearch to my rails application I used searchkick:

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

It is really user friendly and fast to set up. You can use `rake searchkick:reindex:all` command to index all data.

Comment: I didn't get what it's realy doing behind, but it works to me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I worked with tire, but from the top of my head:

- Solution 1: Fire up a rails console and save a new `Movie` object (e.g. `Move.create(...)`). This *might* create the index for you, not sure though.
- Solution 2: Run `rake environment tire:import:all` in the project's root folder This should reindex all your models into ElasticSearch.

Hope that helps.

Update:

```
index = Tire::Index.new('oldskool')
index.delete
index.create
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt.
i already tried both of them.
while trying to execute these it is showing


[ERROR] There has been an error when creating the index -- elasticsearch returned:
500 : {"error":"IndexCreationException[[custom-index-name] failed to create index]; nested: NoClassDefFoundError[Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.PostingFormats]; ","status":500}


& same kind of error for rake environment tire:import:all

Comment: Did it work? The error message basically says, that the movies index hasn't been created yet. You could try to create it programmaticall from within a rails console (`rails c`):
`index = Tire::Index.new('movies')
index.delete
index.create`

Comment: There 3 statements. I updated the answer, the comment messed up the formatting.

Comment: When i trying to execute 2nd & 3rd statement giving false & false ...:(

irb(main):001:0> index = Tire::Index.new('movie')
=> #<Tire::Index:0x0000000433b630 @name="movie">
irb(main):002:0> index.delete
=> false
irb(main):003:0> index.create
=> false